# event.target on ie 8

Tags: jquery

jquery newbie here.

Is there a problem using **event.target** in ie8?

It seems to be working in ie9 and on my android.

This is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       $('#myMenu')[0].onclick = function(event) {
       var selected = event.target.innerHTML;
       var url = 'RedirectMenu.aspx?val=' + selected;
       location.href = url;
       }
   });
 </script>
```

The html is

```
 <ul id="myMenu">
 <li><a href="#">Generic Clinical Tasks</a></li> 

 <li><a href="#">Facility</a>   
    <ul class="level2">
     <li><a href="#">Change Facility or Unit  </a></li> 
     <li><a href="#">Edit Facility nformation</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">Doctors</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Nurses</a></li> 
    </ul>
</li>

 <li><a href="#">Patient</a>   
    <ul class="level2">
etc...
```

To clarify - as I said I am a newbie. This is how I was able to get the item selected, not just that one of the menu items was clicked.

How am I supposed to do this using jquery?

Right now, the value of 'selected'

var selected = event.target.innerHTML;

is Doctor, when the Doctor menu item is clicked.

Comment: What happens when you use it in IE8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642095/access-event-target-in-ie8-unobstrusive-javascript

Comment: !error on page . nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery. You can bind **[click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** event like below,

```
   $(function() {

       $('li', $('#MyMenu').click(function(event) {
          var selected = $(this).text(); // event.target.innerHTML;
          var url = 'RedirectMenu.aspx?val=' + selected;
          location.href = url;
       });
   });
```

Comment: Is there any benefit to using `event.target` over something like `$('#myMenu').on('click', 'a', function () {... var selected = this.innerHTML; ...})`?

Comment: `$('#myMenu').on('click'` binds an event.. Setting `onclick` attribute simply can one function unless you call it yourself internally.

Comment: @vega: Much prettier. But your code returns all the html for the menu, mine just the selected text on the menu item. I had tried diff versions of what you suggested and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @LillLansey Need to see your html. I thought you want the html of the element you clicked which includes the child elements.

Comment: @Vega, I meant `event.target` over `this`.

Comment: @LillLansey So in that HTML which text (e.targer.innerHTML) you want to be passed?  Is it the li or just the text "Generic Clinical Tasks"?

Comment: @vega just the text "Generic Clinical Tasks"

Comment: @LillLansey Try updated post.. which binds the click event to the `li` so that you can get the text of that specific li.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for click handling. Showing your html would help better answer your question.

```
$("#myMenu").click(function() {
  var url = 'RedirectMenu.aspx?val=' + $(this).html();
  location.href = url;
});
```