# "On" event does not work in IE8 with dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've got a grid with code below:

```
<div>
<table id="grid" class="display">
    <thead>
        ....
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

that is filled with appropriate data via ajax requests. Some `<td>` elements also contain dynamically added links. So, when I'm trying to bind click event to them, it doesn't work in IE8.

```
var $grid = $("#grid");
...
$grid.on("click", "tbody a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

It works perfectly fine everywhere except IE8.

**Could someone explain me, where I'm wrong and how to solve this problem? (I'm  using jQuery 1.9.1)**

Comment: Any errors on console.?

Comment: @Bhavesh He is correctly using the `on` method to do so. So your comment isn't true here

Comment: Your code should work fine. Can you create a working example of the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: can you share the link to application or fiddle ?

Comment: Have you tried using `$grid.click(function (e) {` instead?

Comment: For the guys who requested a JSfiddle, here is one with ajax data loading.
But since JSfiddle website will not be displayed correctly on IE8... I don't think it will really help ^^
http://jsfiddle.net/8KqU7/3/

We would also need to see the rest of your code if possible.
There might be something in your CSS or with other scripts that would cause this trouble.

Comment: Have you seen this question? It looks like preventDefault doesn't work in IE8 and jQuery just sticks a stub method in there to fill out the API interface. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20568261/605232

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your function like following:

```
$grid.on("click", "tbody a", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("clicked!");
});
```

That is because in IE8 the event object is a global property (`window.event`) and not an argument of the handler.

Read more about your problem on
[Quirksmode event order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and [MDN Event differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#Event_differences).

Also on StackOverflow are a lot answers to that: [Acces event target in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642095/access-event-target-in-ie8-unobstrusive-javascript/) or [JavaScript IE event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960419/javascript-ie-event)